# Can't run PHP in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Please help me !
My application has been whitelisted for PHP deployment. I want test my apps but cant run php. I am use windows 7 Ultimate x64.

> Path php: C:\Users\Heroin\php\php-cgi.exe
>
> Path SDK: C:\Users\Heroin\google_appengine
>
> Path Project: C:\Project\BBHOABINH\helloworld\

I runing command line flags:

> google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="C:\Users\Heroin\php\php-cgi.exe" "C:\Project\BBHOABINH\helloworld\"

It's not working for test. 
Errors logs:

```
2013-06-10 00:54:05 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Heroin\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', u'google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', u'--php_executable_path=C:\\Users\\Heroin\\php\\php-cgi.exe helloworld\\', u'C:\\Users\\Heroin\\helloworld']"
usage: dev_appserver.py [-h] [--host HOST] [--port PORT]
                        [--admin_host ADMIN_HOST] [--admin_port ADMIN_PORT]
                        [--auth_domain AUTH_DOMAIN] [--storage_path PATH]
                        [--log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,error}]
                        [--max_server_instances MAX_SERVER_INSTANCES]
                        [--use_mtime_file_watcher [USE_MTIME_FILE_WATCHER]]
                        [--php_executable_path PATH]
                        [--php_remote_debugging [PHP_REMOTE_DEBUGGING]]
                        [--python_startup_script PYTHON_STARTUP_SCRIPT]
                        [--python_startup_args PYTHON_STARTUP_ARGS]
                        [--blobstore_path BLOBSTORE_PATH]
                        [--mysql_host MYSQL_HOST] [--mysql_port MYSQL_PORT]
                        [--mysql_user MYSQL_USER]
                        [--mysql_password MYSQL_PASSWORD]
                        [--mysql_socket MYSQL_SOCKET]
                        [--datastore_path DATASTORE_PATH]
                        [--clear_datastore [CLEAR_DATASTORE]]
                        [--datastore_consistency_policy {consistent,random,time}]
                        [--require_indexes [REQUIRE_INDEXES]]
                        [--auto_id_policy {sequential,scattered}]
                        [--logs_path LOGS_PATH]
                        [--show_mail_body [SHOW_MAIL_BODY]]
                        [--enable_sendmail [ENABLE_SENDMAIL]]
                        [--smtp_host SMTP_HOST] [--smtp_port SMTP_PORT]
                        [--smtp_user SMTP_USER]
                        [--smtp_password SMTP_PASSWORD]
                        [--prospective_search_path PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH_PATH]
                        [--clear_prospective_search [CLEAR_PROSPECTIVE_SEARCH]]
                        [--search_indexes_path SEARCH_INDEXES_PATH]
                        [--clear_search_indexes [CLEAR_SEARCH_INDEXES]]
                        [--enable_task_running [ENABLE_TASK_RUNNING]]
                        [--allow_skipped_files [ALLOW_SKIPPED_FILES]]
                        [--api_port API_PORT]
                        [--automatic_restart [AUTOMATIC_RESTART]]
                        [--dev_appserver_log_level {debug,info,warning,critical,error}]
                        [--skip_sdk_update_check [SKIP_SDK_UPDATE_CHECK]]
                        yaml_files [yaml_files ...]
**dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:\Users\Heroin\helloworld
2013-06-10 00:54:06 (Process exited with code 2)**
```

This yaml_files

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php
```

and helloworld php file

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
  </head>
<body>  
<?php
  echo 'Hello, World!';
 php?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me, thank you :(

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the double quotation marks in your command:

Try:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=C:\Users\Heroin\php\php-cgi.exe   C:\Project\BBHOABINH\helloworld\
```

happy coding!